# Built web view for outputting log as a stream (just like the console)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, streaming

I have a rails app with some web tools built for debugging. I would like to make a view, that monitors the log of a backgroundprocess, and streams it, just like when tailing the log in the console. How can I built that, what should I use to stream it to the webpage (JS, web sockets, Pusher)?

An example or something would be helpful.

Comment: I think `faye-rails` gem could help you. try using it to listen to the log file.

Comment: I think you should have a look at browserlog gem https://github.com/dieb/browserlog, it provides console log in webpage you can have a reference from it